# I am new to android development. is it possible to create a recyclerView without Model class?. with a built in data from firebase?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

My problem is that I have two android app, one for Admin and One for Users and has the same database.

Now I Want to implement Recycler View from user Homepage but the data are retrieve in Admin accounts using real time database in firebase. pls help me

I have created Recycler View but it has Model class. is it possible to duplicate them and link with each other?

Comment: Sure, it's totally feasible to work directly with a `DataSnapshot`. If you're having trouble making this work, edit your question to include the [minimal, standalone code that any of us can run to reproduce the question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link please, it's quite useful).

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.